# Raster:area() in R before and after projecting data

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, area, shape-area

I have the following snippet of code:

```
tracts<-readOGR('data/.')
proj4string(tracts)
"+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"

tracts_projected <- spTransform(tracts, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
proj4string(tracts_projected)
"+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

If I take the min area of both, the values are different, even though both spatialpolygondataframes are the same except for the difference in projection.

```
min(area(tracts)/1000000)
 1.221094e-05

min(area(tracts_projected)/1000000)
9.505325e-06
```

Why is this so? And more importantly which is the better way to get area

Comment: Mercator "+proj=merc" is no good for area, it's designed for lines of constant bearing and not area calculations,  I would compare the result from `tracts_projected` (which is calculated using an approximation in longitude/latitude) with `area(spTransform(tracts, "+proj=laea +datum=WGS84")) ` (an equal area projection)- but, it might be better to transform to a local centre - so please `print(tracts)` and show us the output, and also `plot(tracts); axis(1); axis(2)` to show us how the data looks.